# Error by installing UIMA in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, uima, eclipse-neon

I am trying to install UIMA in Eclipse, but I am getting an error 
"An error occured while collecting items to be installed." Then it says some artifacts are not found. 
Do someone know what does it mean and how can I install UIMA?

Comment: Did you enabled the checkbox "Contact all update sites during install..." in the installation dialog?

Comment: The problem is solved, you need to install only the first item from three which Eclipse shows you after putting the site address. Then it works.